# Erlcloud SQS message not sent

Tags: erlang, amazon-sqs

Using the Erlcloud library for erlang I tried sending a message to the SQS,
`erlcloud_sqs:send_message("ErlangGamesPacket","hi")` for this command I am getting in return `[{message_id,"8e4a535a-961f-4bc2-bd32-408d665b9323"},
 {md5_of_message_body,"c1a5298f939e87e8f962a5edfc206918"}]`
but on checking in the console its shows "No message recieved". 
Do anyone know anything regarding this?

Comment: If there is an error there I'd be very confused. You seem to get a proper response from SQS. Are you sure that nobody is consuming messages and the topic is configured correctly to retain them for enough time and you are checking the right topic? Does posting to the queue via a different mechanism work?